# buildroot with external toolchain generated with same buildroot

Tags: linux, buildroot

I am using buildroot to build toolchain which will be used later with same buildroot version.
According documentation, SDK creates as an archive in images folder. It contains compiler with libraries and host utilites. But whien I build my project in buildroot sing this toolchain as external, buildroot builds host utils again. Can buildroot use host utils placed in toolchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buildroot only uses the toolchain (= compiler, binutils, and libc) from an external toolchain. The other host tools are present in the SDK, but Buildroot will still (re)build them if they are needed for the configuration.

The reason for this is that using anything from the environment creates a risk of things being not reproducible. In this case, because the host tools come from Buildroot itself, there is no such risk, but it's not easy to determine that a given external toolchain is actually a Buildroot SDK.